# Servicestack ORMLite and FirebirdSQL - Autoincrement doesn't work

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack, firebird2.5

My class `Users` in C#:

```
public class Users
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Index(Unique = true)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

I used :

```
db.CreateTable<Users>(overwrite: false);
```

to create the table in the database.

The debug output shows :

```
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Information: 0 : Command:
CREATE TABLE Users 
(
  Id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  Username VARCHAR(100), 
  "Password" VARCHAR(250), 
  PRIMARY KEY(Id) 
); 

Parameters:

FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Information: 0 : Command:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_users_username ON Users (Username ); 

Parameters:

FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Information: 0 : Command:
CREATE GENERATOR USERS_ID_GEN;
Parameters:
```

But when I am trying to insert a record, Firebird complains about the empty `Id` field.

C#:

```
db.Insert(new Users { Username = "admin", Password = "passwordhere" });
```

Debug Output:

```
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Information: 0 : Command:
INSERT INTO Users (Username,"Password") VALUES (@Username,@Password)
Parameters:
Name:@Username  Type:VarChar    Used Value:admin
Name:@Password  Type:VarChar    Used  Value:passwordhere
```

Exception:

> validation error for column ID, value "*** null ***"

I uses the latest versions form `NuGet`. Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a trigger for the autoincrement, Firebird 2.5 and earlier do not actually have an identity column; this is simulated using a sequence and a trigger?

Comment: Hi Mark, no theres no Trigger. I thought ORMLite create it automatically when i call db.CreateTable.

Comment: If there is not trigger, then either ORMLite uses the sequence directly, or this might be a bug in ORMLite.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. The problem is that the trigger which is supposed to generate the new Id is not created when table is created, only the sequence is generated. Any development in this area? Thanks!